# I am not using freemarker for struts2, but I see lots of logging generated by freemarker

Tags: java, logging, configuration, struts2, freemarker

I am using struts 2 and jsp for my web application, but I am seeing a lot of freemarker debugging message generated on my console.

I have turn off the logging using slf4j and log4j2 configurations. However, looking deeper into the configurations.

It seems that freemarker is included in the struts-default package, and by extending it, I will include freemarker support in my web application as well.

Did I misconfigure my struts.xml configuration? Is disabling the output to console the only way to go?

How do I "remove" freemarker from my application?

my struts.xml

```
<package name="test" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
```

struts-default.xml

```xml
<package name="struts-default" abstract="true" strict-method-invocation="true">
    <result-types>
        <result-type name="chain" class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionChainResult"/>
        <result-type name="dispatcher" class="org.apache.struts2.result.ServletDispatcherResult" default="true"/>
        <result-type name="freemarker" class="org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerResult"/>
        <result-type name="httpheader" class="org.apache.struts2.result.HttpHeaderResult"/>
        <result-type name="redirect" class="org.apache.struts2.result.ServletRedirectResult"/>
        <result-type name="redirectAction" class="org.apache.struts2.result.ServletActionRedirectResult"/>
        <result-type name="stream" class="org.apache.struts2.result.StreamResult"/>
        <result-type name="velocity" class="org.apache.struts2.result.VelocityResult"/>
        <result-type name="xslt" class="org.apache.struts2.views.xslt.XSLTResult"/>
        <result-type name="plainText" class="org.apache.struts2.result.PlainTextResult" />
        <result-type name="postback" class="org.apache.struts2.result.PostbackResult" />
    </result-types>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Roman, I downloaded a blank struts2 war file from maven and did not expected freemarker to generate log statements like this. However, I have managed to resolve it based on a FreeMarker FAQ. I have posted the link below and hopefully helpful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struts2 uses *THEMEs* to generate code from Struts tags;

a *THEME* is a collection of *TEMPLATEs* (one for each tag);

this *TEMPLATEs* (in struts2-core-xxx.jar -> template) are FreeMarker Templates.

Then you are not using Freemarker directly (for example [in place of the JSPs](https://struts.apache.org/docs/using-freemarker-templates.html)), but Struts2 uses Freemarker implicitly, and you cannot remove it.

---

XY: your logging-pollution problem can be resolved by raising the server level to ERROR, and your application to DEBUG, instead of having the whole server to DEBUG.

Comment: Based on this FAQ http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_misc_logging.html, you have to include slf4j and turn it off via log4j configurations.

Comment: Good. Consider adding another answer to your question,summarizing the configuration process